# Converting \n in C# to a new line in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am re-wrting this agian as people dont seem to understand what i want.

I am presenting a table with information from my SQL database. When i insert into my SQL database i add

```
\n
```

so when i 'draw' the database i can just replace it with

```
<br>
```

and it will add a new line. Heres what i tired and it doesnt seem to work:

[image: Image of me replacing the string]

But that doesnt seem to work, it wont replace the strings, but if i replace '$row['Info']' with something like "Hello \n Test" it will print hello and Test onto seperate lines.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying you want to remove the new lines before inserting it into the database or add them before putting it in the database? If you want to add them, just use \n like you did, but you may want to replace \n with <br /> on retrieval so that they are visible in a web browser. If you want to remove the \n before the insertion, simply use str_replace() and remove them.

Comment: So if there is multiple lines in the code, the database will just add it like that? o.0

Comment: @Cacoon - try echoing $row['info'] and let me know what it returns. It would also be helpful if you could look at the actual database record before retrieving it (through a MySQL client such as Sequel or phpMyAdmin etc) so you can see if it has the new lines stored in the actual database entry. If you want, contact me through my website at mdl.fm and I can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

In your string replacement function, replace

```
"\n"
```

With

```
"\\n"
```

As the escaping cancels the first one out.